# Mutual authentication : "Received fatal alert: handshake_failure" after ServerHelloDone

Tags: security, ssl, openssl, tls1.2

I need to support mutual authentication between client and server. Till now one-way authentication is working i.e. we are able to validate certs against CA certificate stored in the trust store.

For mutual authentication, I performed below step :

1. Download CA certificate in PEM format.
2. Copy this to Client and convert this into CRT format and install it on Client VM using below command:
   sudo /usr/java/default/bin/keytool -import -alias $file_name -file $file_name.crt -keystore /usr/java/default/jre/lib/security/cacerts -storepass changeit -noprompt
3. Get the Client certificate from CA same as above.
4. I copied this cert (again in PEM format) to Client VM and convert this to CRT extension.
5. I installed this client cert in keystore location which is different than trust store with below command 
   sudo /usr/java/default/bin/keytool -import -alias $file_name -file $file_name.crt -keystore keystore.jks -storepass changeit -noprompt
6. I created SSLContext as below
   sslContext.init(keyManagers, trustStore, NULL_SECURE_RANDOM);
7. Now we are trying to communicate to server from client and I am getting handshake failure error

   ```
   <HASH_VALUE>
   main, READ: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 333
   *** ECDH ServerKeyExchange
   Signature Algorithm SHA512withRSA
   Server key: Sun EC public key, 256 bits
     public x coord: 10253619320081805931384466854469954543531656069378199159702043393618555071374
     public y coord: 88104986257121586743271984238217759117375506314354198659212202676684306616776
     parameters: secp256r1 [NIST P-256, X9.62 prime256v1] (1.2.840.10045.3.1.7)
   [read] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 333

   main, READ: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 453
   *** CertificateRequest
   Cert Types: ECDSA, RSA, DSS
   Supported Signature Algorithms: SHA512withECDSA, SHA512withRSA, SHA384withECDSA, SHA384withRSA, SHA256withECDSA, SHA256withRSA, SHA224withECDSA, SHA224withRSA, SHA1withECDSA, SHA1withRSA, SHA1withDSA
   Cert Authorities:
   <O=saurav, OU=xxx, C=IN, CN=XX_CA>
   <O=saurav, OU=xxx, C=IN, CN=YY_CA>
   <O=saurav, OU=xxx, C=IN, CN=ZZ_CA>
   <O=saurav, OU=xxx, C=IN, CN=XX_CA>
   <O=saurav, OU=xxx, C=IN, CN=YY_CA>
                 ....
   main, READ: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 4
   *** ServerHelloDone
   [read] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 4
   0000: 0E 00 00 00                                        ....
   Warning: no suitable certificate found - continuing without client authentication
   *** Certificate chain
   <Empty>
   ***
   *** ECDHClientKeyExchange
   ECDH Public value:  {.... }
   [write] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 77

   main, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 77
                                                .1
   INSSION KEYGEN:
   PreMaster Secret:
   0000: A2 ED 45 23 FE D5 CF 02   49 B2 28 1F 37 1A C6 EA  ..E#....I.(.7...
   0010: CF DE E7 E8 11 A5 2F 2D   1F CE 89 B4 BE D3 D3 92  ....../-........
   CONNECTION KEYGEN:
   Client Nonce:
   0000: 5A F4 46 1C A1 65 28 10   49 E5 8A 47 8C 10 AD 98  Z.F..e(.I..G....
   0010: 21 BA 57 20 DC 48 C2 84   B0 C9 FD 14 B3 41 0B 21  !.W .H.......A.!
   Server Nonce:
   0000: 5A F4 46 1D 0A 7D AA 8D   E3 EE 0B 16 9A 20 D2 00  Z.F.......... ..
   0010: DD 60 36 0C C3 8D 96 1B   94 24 E5 AB 7A C1 D7 14  .`6......$..z...
   Master Secret:
   0000: BA 3E FF B8 EB 4B 5E 70   0F 07 B9 00 F1 10 DD B6  .>...K^p........
   0010: DF AC 69 87 21 B1 BE CD   5E 97 96 55 E4 4C 41 B3  ..i.!...^..U.LA.
   0020: C8 0B FC 2E 4B 08 65 82   82 9A A6 0F AE 39 41 0E  ....K.e......9A.
   Client MAC write INcret:
   0000: 77 34 7D 71 F5 5E 15 8E   14 0B BA A9 C0 11 15 A0  w4.q.^..........
   0010: C1 AA B1 05 3A F0 87 1F   96 EC E0 19 AE 78 39 1B  ....:........x9.
   Server MAC write Secret:
   0000: F7 CB D9 B4 53 D8 8E 37   25 3A E9 1D 1A D9 CB 3D  ....S..7%:.....=
   0010: 80 52 D5 D2 7C 66 AB 99   16 9E D7 EA CE 1F 6F 00  .R...f........o.
   Client write key:
   0000: 69 FD 1A C3 30 D3 0D 72   37 7F 43 4A A9 20 D5 4B  i...0..r7.CJ. .K
   Server write key:
   0000: 86 C9 46 E0 D7 99 A9 24   3F 50 DA 26 C9 0B D8 26  ..F....$?P.&...&
   ... no IV derived for this protocol
   main, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Change Cipher Spec, length = 1
   [Raw write]: length = 6
   0000: 14 03 03 00 01 01                                  ......
   *** Finished
   verify_data:  { 104, 207, 194, 200, 118, 209, 56, 63, 206, 199, 95, 238 }
   ***
   [write] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 16
   ..
   main, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 80
   main, waiting for close_notify or alert: state 1
   [Raw read]: length = 5
   0000: 15 03 03 00 02                                     .....
   [Raw read]: length = 2
   0000: 02 28                                              .(
   main, READ: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
   main, RECV TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, handshake_failure
   %% Invalidated:  [INssion-1, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256]
   main, called closeSocket()
   main, Exception while waiting for close javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
   main, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
   May 10, 2018 1:16:12 PM com.saurav.kumar.rest.impl.RestEasyClient sendRequest
   INVERE: Error sending request
   javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
           at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
           at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:154)
           at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:2038)
           at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1135)
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was two issue with my implementation.

- Issue 1 :
  As mention in my question, I need to create a new keystore and install the cert into it using command "`sudo /usr/java/default/bin/keytool -import -alias $file_name -file $file_name.crt -keystore keystore.jks -storepass changeit -noprompt`". When I was trying to install the client certificate, it was not installing the whole certificate chain. Instead of whole certificate chain, it was just installing the certificate for my application without any CA certificate, which is why no certificates were sent by client as shown in log below

> ```
> Warning: no suitable certificate found - continuing without client authentication
> *** Certificate chain
> <Empty>
> ***
> ```

- Issue 2: Once I fixed the keys store problem, I was getting SSLPeerUnverifiedException as shown below. This is due to the lack of support for IPv6 verification of `org.apache.http.conn.ssl.StrictHostnameVerifier` class. I need to override this class so that it should able to treat IPv6 address properly and validate the same.

> SEVERE: Error sending request
>   javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Host name '[IPv6-IP]' does
>   not match the certificate subject provided by the peer
>   (CN_name_of_cert)
>           at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.verifyHostname(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:465)
>           at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:395)
>           at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:353)
>           at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:141)
>           at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:353)